# How to install pycrypto on qpython?

Tags: android, pycrypto, qpython

I have been using pycrypto on my windows machine running python 2.7. 
When I tried to install pycrypto on qpython2.7 via pip I got Runtime error ("autoconf error"). For reference I am running qpython on stock android nougat with no root access.
Is there any way to install pycrypto for qpython

Not a problem ended up using pyaes instead of pycrypto.

Answer (score 0):

Qpython didn't support pycrypto now, we will consider to support it as soon after we have delivered our brand new version which we were developing.